# Problem in inserting data into many to many relationships using attach() function laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

i have two tables (orders & products) and one pivot table (order_product).
i have made many to many relationship b\w them using following code.

```
class Product extends Model{

   protected $fillable = ['name', 'price', 'is_iframe_product'];

   public function orders() {

      return $this->belongsToMany(Order::class);

   }   
}


class Order extends Model{

    public $guaded = ['id'];

    protected $fillable = ['is_iframe_order','price', 'status', 'address_id','user_id'];

    public function products () {

        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);

    }
}
```

i am using following code to insert records in CheckoutController.php

```
 $Product = array('name' => $item['item_name'], "price" => $item['price'], "is_iframe_product" => "1");
 $saved = order()->products()->attach([$Product]);
```

but getting this error:

> exception: "Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError"
>   file: "C:\wamp3\www\jewellery\jewellery\app\Http\Controllers\CheckoutController.php"
>   line: 63
>   message: "Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\order()"

Answer (score 0):

You're using a *function*: `order()->...`

And the error says the function doesn't exist: `Call to undefined function ... order()`

Did you mean to reference a variable, like this? `$order->...`

It would be helpful if you included the rest of the controller, since I don't know what variables you're using.

Also, your `Order` model has a typo: `$guaded` should be `$guarded`.

Comment: in controller i write this code
        foreach ($cart_items as $item) {
            $total_price = $total_price + (float) $item['price'];
            $Product = array('name' => $item['item_name'], "price" => $item['price'], "is_iframe_product" => "1");

        $saved = $order->products()->attach($product->id);
        }

Answer (score 0):

Here's what to do:

1. First save the product into the database

   `$product = Product::create(array('name' => $item['item_name'], "price" =>$item['price'], "is_iframe_product" => "1"));`
2. Then attach the saved product with the product's `id`

   `$saved = $order->products()->attach($product->id);`

Comment: laravel will return product id automatically by this command?  $product->id

Comment: i tried but this error occur  "message: "Call to a member function products() on array""

Comment: that means the $order is not an Order, but an array. Do $order = Order::first(); before $saved = $order->products()->attach($product->id);

Comment: show the code for the section when you get the order

Comment: I have to create order and products in tha that order.

Comment: I have created order already. Now i want to insert products i  product table . I want to insert product_id and order_id in order_product table. That's exactly i want to achieve

Comment: Then your order will $order, then you should be fine

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is create the order first:

```
$order = new Order;
// set some attributes
$order->save();
```

Then you can attach the specified product:

```
$product = Product::find(1);

$order->products()->attach($product->getKey());
```

If you are creating the product on the fly:

```
$product = Product::create(array('name' => $item['item_name'], "price" =>$item['price'], "is_iframe_product" => "1"));

$order->products()->attach($product->getKey());
```

Comment: why we use  this line?   $product = Product::find(1);

Comment: I made the assumption you will need to find your product.  If you are creating the product on the fly use @Elisha Senoo's answer.

Comment: When i do $pdoduct = Product::find(1). This error occurs" call to undefined function find()."

Comment: `find` is straight from the documentation. If you are getting an undefined function error then your product is not an eloquent model. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#retrieving-single-models